# Shortcut to "Find Related Messages In Conversation"

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Using Outlook 2010, is it possible to bind a keyboard shortcut to the "Find Related -> Messages in this conversation" functionality?

I've tried the "Customize Ribbon" and "Customize Quick Access Toolbar" options to try to get a button that could be bound to an Alt-key combination, but I am unable to find the "Find Related" command, let alone the "Messages in this conversation" subcommand in the list of available commands.  I'm not knowledgeable enough to know whether a macro could be created and bound to a key combination.

Answer (score 6):

The name of the function that you are looking for to add to the "Quick Access Toolbar" is "Messages in this Conversation".  Note that you can only add that to the toolbar for a message item rather than the main Outlook window.  Once you have added it, you can do the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>number</kbd> combination to fire it up from the keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

I do the following;

The keyboard shortcut for showing related conversation emails is to select the email concerned and then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F10</kbd>, then <kbd>F</kbd>, then <kbd>C</kbd>.
I use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to create a macro that sends this key combination, and then create an Outlook Macro that calls the AutoHotKeys macro, and assign a keyboard shortcut to the Outlook Macro.

The AutoHotKey macro is below;

```
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; /Alt-x (Outlook only) Archive Macro
;---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#IfWinActive, Microsoft Outlook
{
$!x::Send +{F10},F,C
return
}
return
#IfWinActive
```

It sounds complicated, but it's the easiest way I could do it!

Hope this helps.

Comment: I switched jobs a couple months after posting the question and no longer use Outlook, so I have no way of evaluating whether this works or not, but it sounds just like what I was looking for at the time!

Comment: To select the email concerned and then press Shift-F10, then F, then C definitely works with my outlook 2010 (v14 32-bit) ... I have autoHotKey but perhaps next time i may try if I tire of outlook shortcuts..Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

for outlook2016

1. right click robin, and select 'Customize the Ribbon'
2. under 'Choose commands from', select 'Commands Not in the Ribbon', find 'Messages in this Conversation' and click.
3. On the right, select Home(Mail), create a new group
4. click 'Add' to add your selected command to your new group

Finally, you can find this command in your ribbon; select one email, click this command should be a quick way.

Answer (score 0):

This works for Outlook 2013

```
#IfWinActive, - Outlook ahk_class rctrl_renwnd32, NUIDocumentWindow;
{
    $!x::Send +{F10},F,C
    return
}
return
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the message in-between inverted comma's in search field by excluding RE:/FW: words, this will show all related messages in one go.